# Difference between bindAsContract and bind in HK2

Tags: dependencies, bind, inject, hk2

I am working to implement a dependency injection of a constructor in a J2EE jersey project. I am using HK2. I create a class

```
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
  @Inject
  public MyServiceImpl(String test){
   // do something
  }
}
```

Now, my question is when I register this dependency injection in a dependencybinder class by extending AbstractBinder, what is the difference between binding the dependency as a simple "bind" vs a "bindAsContract"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use

```java
bind(ServiceImpl.class).to(IService.class)
```

`ServiceImpl` is the implementation class, and `IService` is the *contract* that you advertise as the injection type. So you would use

```java
@Inject
private IService service;
```

With

```java
bindAsContract(ServiceImpl.class)
```

you are saying that `ServiceImpl` is both the implementation class *and* the contract to advertise as. So you would need to inject it as such.

```java
@Inject
private ServiceImpl service;
```

Comment: If I have two classes implementing the same IService interface: (1) FileServiceImpl, (2) Databaseserviceimpl, then how can we inject the appropriate classes through the interface as we need? Do we have to use any qualifier or something like that?

Comment: Yes, you can use `qualifiedBy(annotationInstance)`

Comment: How shall i take care of the constructor arguments in that case?

Comment: You need to bind those as well. In the case you have in your post, since it's a String, you would need to qualify that.